# Subclass object needing to be type cast as the subclass to access subclass methods

Tags: java, inheritance

This is the (abridged) super class:

```
public class Account
{
    private double bal;  //The current balance
    private int accnum;  //The account number


    public Account(int a)
    {    
        bal=0.0;
        accnum=a;
    }
}
```

The subclass:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{

    private static final double INTEREST_RATE = 5;  // Interest amount for savings account

    public SavingsAccount(int a) {
        super(a);
    }

    public void addInterest(){
        double interest = getBalance()/100*INTEREST_RATE;
        deposit(interest);
    }
}
```

And the main code:

```
public class AccountMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare Variables
        Account myAccount = new SavingsAccount(500);

        // Do stuff
        myAccount.deposit(1000);
        System.out.println(myAccount.toString());
        ((SavingsAccount) myAccount).addInterest();
        System.out.println(myAccount.toString());
    }

}
```

Why am I having to cast myAccount as a SavingsAccount when it's been declared as a SavingsAccount?

Everything I've read implies that by declaring the new object as the subclass should make all the superclass and subclass methods available. I feel that I'm missing something but can't find what.

Answer (score 2):

> Why am I having to cast myAccount as a SavingsAccount when it's been declared as a SavingsAccount?

Here is your variable declaration portion:

```
Account myAccount;
```

and so this is how the compiler understands the variable's *type*.

And here is the assignment portion:

```
myAccount = new SavingsAccount(500);
```

This is where you assign a specific object reference to your variable. Note that it does not and cannot change the declared type.

So you can see that the myAccount variable has most definitely **not** been **declared** a SavingsAccount type variable. It has been declared an Account type variable that has been assigned a SavingsAccount type object. You could just as well later change the assignment to another Account type object, and so to be type-safe the compiler will require that you cast the variable if you want to use it as a more specific type.

Answer (score 1):

that is actually the behavior of polymorphism - the **myAccount** object would be considered as **SavingsAccount** only at runtime. in short:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass(); // 'a' type is considered as MyClass in both development & runtime
MySuper b = new MyClass(); // 'b' type is MySuper on development and MyClass on runtime
```

unless you are working with collections there is not a real need to declare your object that way. BUT if collections are required you might:

1. declare the entire collection as your desired type
2. or use an interface instead (if you need to use a common feature that has nothing to do with inheritance)